# AppEngine Taskqueue: is there a way to determine the queue depth?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to determine *programmatically* how many tasks are queued in a taskqueue in AppEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, no.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this question, now you can use the QueueStatistics class to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin console, under **Task Queues**, there is a column labeled *Tasks in Queue*. I believe that's what you want.

Comment: I'd like this capability accessible programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, did I miss that in your question or did you add it later? Anyway I've been considering some sort of scraper that gets the data from the admin console. Besides this, I hate how I have no historical records of my quota usage.